# How to initialise an xmas scan along with idle/zombie scan in nmap

Tags: nmap, websecurity

The issue is providing two flag to nmap scan just complicates the issue.

Tried doing all flag --scanflags , but didnt work that effectively. Also while Performing various other advanced scans no results are showcased until/unless a firewall is configured.